# sql query to get selected records based on min (date) and string compare

Tags: sql, date, subset, min, vertica

I have the following table structures and data.

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| DateField  | StringA | StringB  |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 01/01/2015 | xxx     | abc123   |
| 02/01/2015 | zzz     | abc12345 |
| 03/01/2015 | xxx     | abc      |
| 04/01/2015 | xxx     | abc      |
| 05/01/2015 | xxx     | abc      |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

I will need to get the following type of records, is there a way to get it using 1 SQL statement?

Get all records that fulfill the following:

- If the row data don't have the same value for StringA and StringB (example: first and second rows) AND
- If row N StringA and StringB same as row N+1 StringA and StringB, only get the 1st row N and ignore the rest.

Basically the end result should be:

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| DateField  | StringA | StringB  |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 01/01/2015 | xxx     | abc123   |
| 02/01/2015 | zzz     | abc12345 |
| 03/01/2015 | xxx     | abc      |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: So, you need unique rows based on String A and String B combination?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a grouping on stringa, stringb, pulling the min date:

```
SELECT STRINGA, STRINGB, MIN(DATEFIELD) AS MIN_DATEFIELD
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY STRINGA, STRINGB;
```

The result set will include a MIN_DATEFIELD column which will contain the minimum date for the matching combination of stringa and stringb.

Comment: If you change 'xxx' with 'yyy' for Jan 4th your select will retrieve 4 rows instead of 5. Basically you miss the rule row N same as row N+1 for stringA and B

Answer (score 0):

Use row function

```
with x as
(select datefield, stringA, StringB, Row_number() over (partition by stringA, StringB order by Datefield) row
)

select datefield,stringA,StringB from x where row = 1
```

Comment: f you change 'xxx' with 'yyy' for Jan 4th your select will retrieve 4 rows instead of 5. Basically you miss the rule row N same as row N+1 for stringA and B

Answer (score 0):

I think you want whenever there is a change to `stringA` and `stringB`.  I would use `lag()` for this:

```
with t as 
      select t.*,
             lag(stringA) over (order by datefield) as prev_stringA,
             lag(stringB) over (order by datefield) as prev_stringB
      from t
     )
select t.*
from t
where (stringA <> prev_stringA or prev_stringA is null) or
      (stringB <> prev_stringB or prev_stringB is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently implement this in Vertica by  using `conditional_change_event`. So, if this is your source table:

```
SQL> select * from t3 order by dt ;
     dt     | stra |   strb   
------------+------+----------
 2015-01-01 | xxx  | abc123
 2015-01-02 | zzz  | abc12345
 2015-01-03 | xxx  | abc
 2015-01-04 | xxx  | abc
 2015-01-05 | xxx  | abc
```

You can run...

```
SQL> select 
        min(dt) as dt, min(stra) as stra, min(strb) as strb
     from (
        select 
            dt, stra, strb, 
            conditional_change_event(stra || strb) over(order by dt) as cce 
        from t3 
     ) b
     group by cce
     order by 1 ;
    min     | stra |   strb   
------------+------+----------
 2015-01-01 | xxx  | abc123
 2015-01-02 | zzz  | abc12345
 2015-01-03 | xxx  | abc
```